# What kind of coin is this? (From Jordan?)

Tags: identification, numismatics

15 years ago I bought an old looking coin in Jordan in the vicinity of old Roman temples. The diameter is aboout 14 mm.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you possibly add a few better (less blurry photographs)  also what is the weight of the coin.

Comment: What metal does the coin appear to be made of?    The bottom picture looks like it has an image of a Hellenistic, Roman, or Medieval rulers, while the top image looks like it has something like a Roman standard.  That could be the standard of a Hellenistic(?) or Roman military unit, or a religious standard connected to a temple.

Comment: This appears to be a follis of Constantine I or II  I'm no expert, but not being able to find a match for the letters on the reverse and the wobbliness of the standard make me wonder if it is an (ancient) fake? I also suspect that the second picture is flipped; can this be confirmed?

Comment: by taking its volume and weight i think you can get a good idea of metal (if pure). btw, looks like you have not tried to clean it -- great, don't do it! touch it as little as possible.